# How to assign a vault policy to a ldap group/user

Tags: ldap, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to use vault in my application. The authentication mechanism i am using is LDAP. I have done the configuration and my users are able to login to vault but they are not able to see any secret engines that I created as a root user.

For example I have enabled a secret engine `secrets/kv` and created 2 keys inside it. What i want is my ldap users to read/write secrets directly from UI. My policy file looks like this -

```
path "secret/kv"
{
  capabilities = ["read", "update", "list"]
}

path "auth/*"
{
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
}
```

And use issued the below command to write the data -
`vault write auth/ldap/groups/ldap-group policies=my-policy`

Still the users can't see the kv engine on the UI to read/write secrets.

Let me know if anyone can help me with this.

Comment: if you are going through the UI, you might need `list` on `/sys/mounts` to be able to list the available mounts. One way to see if this is the problem, is use the url to view only the secret you have access to, for example if i have access to `secrets/test`, i'd use http://127.0.0.1:8200/ui/vault/secrets/secret/show/test

Answer (score 0):

This policy should solve your issue.You don't need to prefix the path with `secret`.

```
path "kv/*"
{
  capabilities = ["read", "update", "list"]
}
```